# How to use dict comprehension to initialize a dictionary that simulates coin flips?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am making a coin flipping simulation (1 being heads and 0 tails) and I want to know if I can do this code in one line using dict comprehension:

```
    from random import randint

    def flip(trials = 1000):

        adict = {'0' : 0, '1' : 0}

        for i in range(trials):
            k = randint(0,1)
            adict[str(k)] += 1
        print adict

    flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `collections.Counter` and a generator expression (instead of dict comprehension)

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(str(randint(0, 1)) for _ in range(trials))
```

It is possible to do everything on one line, but in your case it'll get quite ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you one element. You need to subtract to get the other element:

```
sum([randint for x in range(0, 100)])
```